# In chef server, how to determine when a node is fully bootstrapped

Tags: python, chef-infra

From python, I am using knife to launch a server.

e.g.

```
knife ec2 server create -r "role[nginx_server]" --region ap-southeast-1 -Z ap-southeast-1a -I ami-ae1a5dfc --flavor t1.micro -G nginx -x ubuntu -S sg_development -i  /home/ubuntu/.ec2/sg_development.pem -N webserver1
```

I will then use the chef-server api to check for when the bootstrap is complete so I can then use boto and other tools to configure the newly created server.  Pseudo code will look like this:

```
cmd = """knife ec2 server create -r "role[nginx_server]...."""
os.system(cmd)
boot = False
while boot==False:
    chefTrigger = getStatusFromChefApi()
    if chefTrigger==True:
       boot=True

continue with code for further proccessing
```

My question is: What is the trigger in the chef-server that will indicate when the node is fully processed by chef?  Note, I used the -N to name the server and will query its properties, but what do I look for?  Is there a bool?  A status?

Thanks

Comment: jtimberman's answer below addresses your question.

I would ask the larger question of why you are using boto and other tools, outside of Chef, to configure this instance.

Maybe I am missing something, but you appear to be not fully exploiting the power of Chef here.

Comment: Once booted, I modify tag names, do testing etc before nodes are moved into the load balancer.  I am sure I can do that in chef but I prefer monitoring scripts to do that.  This is a failover solution.  This biggest reason is that if I use chef to boot a failed ec2 naode, I need do know that is booted properly.  It takes about 15 minutes to bootstrap a node.  I have a time out at 20.  If longer, abort and try again. I have noticed that for random reasons with chef, sometimes bootstraps just dont work the first time.  I call it the chef bomb!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: Use a [report/exception handler](http://docs.chef.io/handlers.html) instead.

When the node has finished running `chef-client` successfully, it will save the node object to the Chef Server. One of the attributes automatically generated by [ohai](http://rubygems.org/gems/ohai) every time Chef runs is `node['ohai_time']`, which is the Unix epoch timestamp when ohai was executed (at the beginning of the Chef run). A node that has not successfully saved itself to the server will not have the ohai_time at all. However, this attribute merely tracks the time when ohai ran, not necessarily when `chef-client` saved to the server (since that can be a few seconds to minutes depending on what your recipes are doing). *Note* if the chef run exits due to an unhandled exception, it won't save to the server by default.

A more reliable way to be notified when a node has completed is to use a Report/Exception handler, which can send a message to a variety of places and APIs. See the [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/handlers/) for more information.

Comment: We have used report/exception handlers driving a RabbitMQ queue as a great way to synchronize things.