# If node object is updated after each chef-client run, can use node attribute modification to indicate the end of initial run?

Tags: attributes, chef-infra, monitor

I have a monitoring system that needs to know when a node's initial chef-client run is done.

[Using handler is a way to go here too,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986283/in-chef-server-how-to-determine-when-a-node-is-fully-bootstraped/10000055#10000055) I am thinking letting the handler modify an attribute and save the node object back to chef-server.

[According to the doc](https://docs.chef.io/server_orgs.html):

> Chef reporting data is collected during the chef-client run and the
>   results are posted to the Chef server at the end of the chef-client
>   run at the same time the node object is uploaded to the Chef server.

It seems that the node object is already saved to chef-server in the end then. So, theoretically all I have to do is to modify my attribute somewhere in my cookbook, and the modified attribute will be saved to chef-server after it bootstrapped.

Is this correct?

Comment: Polling the node data will certainly work, and as everything in Chef there are 3 ways to do anything :-) I would recommend sticking with handlers for external system notification (push approach), but it your chef run is involved in a workflow I would considering using Chef tags as an alternative to a node attribute. The Chef DSL supports the setting and unsetting of node tags.

Answer (score 1):

That would be very fragile.  There are many ways to save node data, so assuming that it only happens at the end of a run is dangerous.  You are MUCH better off having your handler directly push data to your monitoring system, rather than having your monitoring system poll it from chef.